# Matrix Rank Error

Tags: matrix, control-systems

I have a linear State Space model and was trying to tell if it was completely controllable. When I get the matrix with ControllabilityMatrix and then calculate the rank I get an incorrect matrix rank that indicates that the system is not completely controllable, but when I run the command with ControllableModelQ it returns True. Why is there discrepancies with the two?

```
A1 = {{0, 0, 0, Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 
    0, -9.81*Cos[\[Theta]], -50/10, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 9.81*Sin[\[Theta]], 
    0, -5, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -100/0.1}} /. {\[Theta] -> Pi/2}

B = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1/10, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1/0.1}}

ssm = StateSpaceModel[{A1, B}, SamplingPeriod -> None, 
  SystemsModelLabels -> None]

MatrixRank[ControllabilityMatrix[ssm]]

ControllableModelQ[ssm]
```

Comment: I don't know what controllable means but try `MatrixRank[ControllabilityMatrix[ssm], Tolerance -> 0]`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you use exact numbers throughout (i.e. replace `-100/0.1` by `-1000`, replace `9.81` by `981/100`, ...) then `ControllabilityMatrix[ssm]` has exact entries and `MatrixRank` returns $6$.

Answer (score 1):

[`ControllableModelQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ControllableModelQ.html) can check this 3 different ways. If any one of them is True, it returns True.

```
AnyTrue[{"Matrix", "Gramian", "PBH"}, 
 Quiet@ControllableModelQ[ssm, Method -> #] &]
(* True *)
```